# How to notify GitHub contributors to my repo that a npm dependency has been updated?

Tags: node.js, git, github, release, package.json

What's the best way to notify contributors to one of my repos on GitHub that a npm dependency has been updated?

For instance, if I update a critical dependency and change the code to incorporate changes in the dep, then the code will not work if the user has not updated their deps. Sometimes the user won't know that they need to update the deps though, unless they check the commit history of package.json.

Is the only real way to notify contributors is to post a new release message on GitHub?

Comment: I think most users would install a module using npm, in which case installing a new version from npm *should* pick up the updated dependency as well.

Comment: Yes but my point is that when users who have already forked my repo then later pull new commits, they usually don't bother to npm update since usually there's no reason to. So how can I make it explicitly clear that updates to package.json have been made, when necessary?

Comment: IMHO people who fork your repo should be knowledgeable enough to keep track of changes. If you really wanted to be proactive about it, you could do some manual dependency version checking in your code at startup and print out some kind of message if the version is too old.

Comment: Sure, that's pretty much how it is now. Contributors are usually smart enough to keep track of package changes themselves, which is fine. I'm looking for a better way though. And yes, I was thinking of just reading package.json myself and going from there, but was wondering if there was an existing solution already.

Comment: Haven't played with it myself, but could you do something with https://greenkeeper.io/

Comment: If you're using gulp, then you could add an updater script to your gulp file